# How to serialize scala object with multiple-arg constructor using Jackson?

Tags: json, scala, serialization, jackson

```
class AgentResponse[T] @JsonCreator()(@JsonProperty("result") val result: T, @JsonProperty("status") val status: ResponseStatus)

class ResponseStatus @JsonCreator()(@JsonProperty("succeeded") val succeeded: Boolean, @JsonProperty("message") val message: String, @JsonProperty("timeStamp") val timeStamp: Long)

new ObjectMapper().registerModule(DefaultScalaModule).writer().writeValue(out, new AgentResponse(result, new ResponseStatus(true, "OK", now)))
```

It throws error :

```
JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class com.fg.mail.smtp.rest.Handler$AgentResponse and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationConfig.SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) )
```

How should the scala object look like for it to work as expected ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from [scala.annotation.meta](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.annotation.meta.package):

> By default, annotations on (`val`-, `var`- or plain) constructor parameters end up on the parameter, not on any other entity. Annotations on fields by default only end up on the field.
>
> The meta-annotations in package `scala.annotation.meta` are used to control where annotations on fields and class parameters are copied. This is done by annotating either the annotation type or the annotation class with one or several of the meta-annotations in this package.

So the annotation goes to the constructor parameter. You need to assign it to the getter as well as the constructor parameter:

```
class MyClass @JsonCreator() (@(JsonProperty @getter @param) val arg: String)
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, you hit the spot.

Comment: @Sloin Just please let me know if it works correctly. I didn't have time to test it.

Comment: I got into a similar problem, unfortunately this one is real :-) https://gist.github.com/l15k4/7027740

Comment: Got it, sorry for bothering :-)